# shell program to modify contents of a file

Tags: shell

I have a file that has a list of product ids each on one line. I want to modify this file in a way that all product ids are on one line and comma separated and in inverted commas. Original format -

```
1\n2\n3\n
```

Expected format -

```
'1','2','3'
```

I tried the following command -

```
paste -s -d "','" velocities.txt > out.txt
```

The result is looking like this -

```
1',2'3'4,
```

I do understand that using the above command I wont get the anything before the first product id, but i will be able to handle that case.

Comment: `-d, --delimiters=LIST  reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs`

Comment: I have already added -d. Are you saying I should be removing it?

Comment: just an explanation why it doesn't work.

Comment: To be more specific, it reads the argument to `-d` as a list of individual one-character separators, and rotates over that list. So you get `'` between columns 1 and 2, `,` between 2 and 3, etc. (Looks like there was an empty line in your input after line 1.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed` to quote all digits:

```
paste -s -d, velocities.txt | sed "s|\([0-9]\+\)|'\1'|g" > out.txt
```

P.S. Another command that also handles IP-addressed:

```
sed "s|^\(.*\)$|'\1'|g" velocities.txt | paste -s -d, - > out.txt
```

Comment: This works for product ids but not for IP addresses. For ip addresses this is the result that I am getting for ip addresses -
'127'.'0'.'0'.'1','10'.'0'.'0'.'1' etc

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. In original post you had use digits and I've created script for digits..